# Can't mount windows 10 partition on ubuntu 16.04 after update

Tags: mount, windows, windows-10

Just what the title says. It's been a while since the update so I'm not sure when exactly it happened.

All I can tell is that when I click on the windows partition icon in my file explorer it doesn't do anything.

I tried mounting windows from a live install of ubuntu and it worked fine.

I am comfortable with the command line but I'm not an advanced user. I am truly grateful for any help on this and would be happy to provide any additional information.

Thank you!

Comment: Can't mount ? What commands are you running, and what errors do you get ?

Comment: @SorenA I'm not running any commands. I use the GUI on the file explorer I have and click on the windows disk partition icon.